# I cannot understand the effectiveness of an algorithm in the Dart SDK

Tags: dart

I cannot understand the effectiveness of an algorithm in the Dart SDK.

Here is the algorithm (List factory in `dart:core`, file `list.dart`)

```dart
factory List.from(Iterable other, { bool growable: true }) {
    List<E> list = new List<E>();
    for (E e in other) {
      list.add(e);
    }
    if (growable) return list;
    int length = list.length;
    List<E> fixedList = new List<E>(length);
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i  ) {
      fixedList[i] = list[i];
    }
    return fixedList;
  }
```

If `growable` is `false` then both lists will be created.

1. `List<E> list = new List<E>();`
2. `List<E> fixedList = new List<E>(length);`

But the creation of list #1 in this case is redundant because it's a duplicate of `Iterable other`. It just wastes CPU time and memory.

In this case this algorithm will be more efficient because it wont create an unnecessary list # 1 (`growable` is `false`).

```dart
factory List.from(Iterable other, { bool growable: true }) {
    if(growable) {
      List<E> list = new List<E>();
      for (E e in other) {
        list.add(e);
      }
      return list;
    }        

    List<E> fixedList = new List<E>(other.length);
    var i = 0;
    for (E e in other) {
      fixedList[i++] = e;
    }
    return fixedList;
  }
```

Or am I wrong and missed some subtleties of programming?

Answer (score 2):

We usually avoid invoking the `length` getter on iterables since it can have linear performance and side-effects. For Example:

```dart
List list = [1, 2, 3];
Iterable iterable1 = list.map((x) {
  print(x);
  return x + 1;
});
Iterable iterable2 = iterable1.where((x) => x > 2);
var fixedList = new List.from(iterable2, growable: false);
```

If `List.from` invoked the `length` getter it would run over all elements twice (`where` does not cache its result). It would furthermore execute the side-effect (printing 1, 2, 3) twice. For more information on Iterables look [here](http://www.dartlang.org/articles/m3-whats-new/iterables.html).

Eventually we want to change the `List.from` code so that we avoid the second allocation and the copying. To do this we need (internal) functionality that transforms a growable list into a fixed-length list. Tracking bug: http://dartbug.com/9459

Comment: Given that Dart does not support `coroutines` and `yield` operator may assume that most of the `length` implementation in `Iterable` will be confined to the delegation. `int get length => collection.length;`. What is not so resource-intensive.

Comment: Iterables frequently have O(n) `length` implementations and have side-effects. I added an example.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it was just an incremental update to the existing function.

See [this commit](https://codereview.chromium.org/12328104/patch/10002/6065) and [this diff](https://code.google.com/p/dart/source/diff?path=/branches/bleeding_edge/dart/sdk/lib/core/list.dart&format=side&r=19112&old_path=/branches/bleeding_edge/dart/sdk/lib/core/list.dart&old=18615)

The function started just with

```
List<E> list = new List<E>();
for (E e in other) {
  list.add(e);
}
```

and had some more bits added as part of a [fairly major refactoring of numerous libraries](https://codereview.chromium.org//12328104).

I would say that the best thing to do is to raise a bug report on dartbug.com, and either add a patch, or commit a CL - see instructions here: https://code.google.com/p/dart/wiki/Contributing  (Note, you do need to jump through some hoops first, but once you're set up, it's all good).

It might also be worth dropping a note to one of the committers or reviewers from the original commit to let them know your plans.

Comment: You say "the best thing to do is to raise a bug report on dartbug.com"? So you think that stackoverflow.com is not the place for such questions about programming? 4 months and 1 week a very long time. That's how long it (implementation) exists.

Comment: You think it's better to have 100 opportunities of average quality rather than 70 of good quality or even 50 of higher quality? I would choose 50 instead of 100.

Comment: By my comment, I meant that it looks like you've given a potential  alternative implementation in your question.  Your next step could be to take your implementation and put it into Dart (which is open source).  The steps to do that are: 1. raise a bug report, 2. add your change in a CL, 3. get it reviewed, 4. get it committed.  Anyone can do this, but _you_ might as well get the credit.

Comment: It is a good idea to ask stack overflow first (and Dart devs, like me, frequently read StackOverflow). If it turns out that Dart is doing something wrong, don't hesitate to file a bug, so that we can investigate further or track the progress of its resolution. In any case we welcome contributions (although I recommend to talk to us first to avoid duplicated work or similar).